# Do decentralized arbitration markets satisfy mitzvah to set up courts?

Tags: technology, beit-din-court, noachide-laws

Do decentralized arbitration markets like Aragon satisfy the noahide mitzvah to set up courts?

Context: Aragon is a decentralized arbitration market, rather than being tied to any one nation-state it is borderless, blockchain-based and Internet-native. Anyone can participate and become an arbitrator(judge) and anyone can submit their dispute to the market(court). The mechanism for deciding disputes is a novel Schelling, stake-based mechanism, I presume this has bearing on it's halachic status.

https://aragon.org/network

Aragon bills itself as "the first Digital Jurisdiction". But it's very likely that several "competitors" will pop up.

Perhaps an additional question: what bearing, if any, could systems like Aragon have on rabbinical courts?

Comment: Seems very bad solution

Comment: I suspect not, because it can only deal with civil disputes, or maybe penal cases where someone (e.g. the family of a murder victim) brings suit. But Noahide courts are meant to enforce all the other 6 mitzvot: who sues in a case of ever min hachai?